# Does the Earth's magnetic field lag behind the Earth as Earth orbits the sun?

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, astronomy, earth, sun

I imagine that when the earth orbits the sun, the earth's magnetic field is also subject to the sun's gravity, since photons and light are subject to gravity.  As a result, the magnetic field does not lag behind the Earth as Earth orbits the sun.  Is this confirmed by observations?  Or does the magnetic field lag the Earth's motion due to light-time delay of having to reset itself as Earth moves?

Comment: Have you searched online for the pictures of the shape of the magnetic field?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a magnetic field.

Comment: You're looking for Faraday's law of induction.

Comment: You should specify the frame of reference since the magnetic and electric field differ from observer to observer

Comment: HomoVafer, it's the same reference frame as the Earth's position and tangential velocity as it orbits the sun.